# HttpsURLConnection works while i have no ssl on the domain

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

i have no ssl on my domain but HttpsURLConnection works without any problem! 
when i use HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection the result is the same.
any idea why?
`

```
private static String Request(String query) throws IOException
    {
        URL url=new URL("https://www.example.com/main.php");
        HttpsURLConnection connection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset",CHARSET);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form- 
            urlencoded;charset="+CHARSET);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(query.length());
        // write request
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.print(query);
        out.close();
        // read response
        InputStream is=connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
        while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null)
            response.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        inputLine=response.toString();
        connection.disconnect();
        return inputLine;
    }
```

`

Comment: I would suggest its because you've made a mistake, and one of your assumptions is false. I assume you'd know if you have SSL on your server or not, so: perhaps your running stale code? Maybe try a tcpdump on the server and see what port it's going to.